# Randomly assign objects to `K` clusters, according to a Dirichlet Multinomial Distribution

Tags: r, multinomial

I'm trying to clusterize short documents like, e.g., the following

```
sentences<-c("The color blue neutralizes orange yellow reflections.", 
             "Zod stabbed me with blue Kryptonite.", 
             "Because blue is your favourite colour.",
             "Red is wrong, blue is right.",
             "You and I are going to yellowstone.",
             "Van Gogh looked for some yellow at sunset.",
             "You ruined my beautiful green dress.",
             "You do not agree.",
             "There's nothing wrong with green.")
```

In the initialization step of my code, I should randomly assign the documents to `K` clusters, according to a Dirichlet Multinomial Distribution.

How could I perform this task?

**Edit** Thanks to @ags29's comment, I found in [Sampling from Dirichlet-Multinomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145530/sampling-from-dirichlet-multinomial)

```
D=9  # number of documents in the corpus; I have 9 sentences in my example
k=2 # number of clusters (e.g. 2)
alpha=runif(D) # value of alpha, here chosen at random
p=rgamma(D,alpha) # pre-simulation of the Dirichlet
x=rmultinom(1,k,p)
```

What do you think?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145530/sampling-from-dirichlet-multinomial

Comment: @ags29 thank you! I edited my post